# I am working in datastage and I am trying to input data from one column to another

Tags: sql, sql-server, datastage

I used the following statement below:

```
Trim(IF FromDataSource.PID_VALID = 'Y' THEN FromDataSource.Person_ID ELSE @NULL)
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using this code within a Transformer stage in DataStage 
this will help

```
IF Trim(FromDataSource.PID_VALID) = 'Y' THEN Trim(FromDataSource.Person_ID) ELSE @NULL
```

Hint:
For you next question you might ask in this forum you should provide more details - do not let us guess. Also describe what you have tried and what error you got etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `case` expression :

```
(CASE WHEN FromDataSource.PID_VALID = 'Y' THEN TRIM(FromDataSource.Person_ID) END)
```

`else` will  return `null` if condition evaluate as false, you don't need to specify `null`.

Comment: I cant use an case statement in datastage

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set null if PID is not valid then->

IF FromDataSource.PID_VALID = 'Y' THEN trim(FromDataSource.Person_ID) ELSE setnull()

If you want to set empty when PID is not valid then->

IF FromDataSource.PID_VALID = 'Y' THEN trim(FromDataSource.Person_ID) ELSE ''